# Passing a parameter to a vim function

Tags: vim

I'm certain that there's going to be a simple answer to this, but I haven't yet hit on the correct part of tutorials and howtos.

I have a function in my .vimrc to help with generating HTML. It's a simple function to wrap selected text in a tag with a given name. Currently, the function signature looks like this:

```
function! WrapInTag( tag )
```

And I have a map set up like this:

```
vmap <Leader>tag <Esc>:call WrapInTag( tagname )<CR>
```

That `tagname` is the issue. How do I configure this so that I can select a block of text, type `\tag b<CR>` and have the highlighted text surrounded by `b` tags? Links to incredibly obvious tutorials that I haven't found yet will be much appreciated.

*Edit* After the fact, I feel it's worth pointing out that it was the user interaction to retrieve the tag name that was stumping me, not selecting the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has less to do with passing arguments to functions (you've got that in your example already), but rather how to interact with the user, i.e. how to get the tag name and the selected text.

For the first, Vimscript offers two functions, `getchar()` for single characters and `input()` for text acknowledged with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Something like this should work:

```
vnoremap <Leader>tag <Esc>:call WrapInTag( nr2char(getchar()) )<CR>
```

(Note: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.)

The text selection is stored in the registers `'<` and `'>`. You can use the ``` `` ``` movement command (or `cursor()`) to go there, or reselect the selection and replace it, e.g. `:normal! gvcNEW-TEXT`.

I hope this gets you started. Don't forget to consult with the excellent help and find similar plugins on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/) to see how they've implemented things.

Comment: The input() function was exactly what I was after, thanks! I've got it working, so now it's time to reread the relevant chapters in "Learning vim" and work out what all the bits of cobbled together vimscript are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Delete your function and install [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697).

Comment: If he's trying it for educational purposes he deserves a more comprehensive answer than this...

Comment: I'll certainly bookmark surround for later, but I'm trying to learn more about my preferred editor so that I can be more efficient with it. Learning proper function handling seems like a good way to go with that.

Comment: I totally agree but I don't have vim at hand so I wouldn't be able to provide a more educative answer at the moment.